# Neo4j: GraphDatabaseService.registerTransactionEventHandler() does not seem to work

Tags: neo4j

Regarding [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18096016/neo4j-cant-get-a-custom-pluginlifecycle-implementation-to-work-in-an-embedded):

I have a problem with `GraphDatabaseService.registerTransactionEventHandler()`. When I try to run [this test](https://github.com/ttiurani/neo4j-uuid/blob/master/src/test/java/org/neo4j/extension/uuid/UUIDTransactionEventHandlerTest.java) against [this handler](https://github.com/ttiurani/neo4j-uuid/blob/master/src/main/java/org/neo4j/extension/uuid/UUIDTransactionEventHandler.java), I don't get any calls to the `beforeCommit` method when running 1.9.2 and only once for a new database for 2.0.0-M03, and for that `TransactionData.createdNodes()` returns an empty iterator even though a a node has been created. The test fails with `org.neo4j.kernel.api.exceptions.PropertyKeyNotFoundException: Property key 'uuid' not found` for these reasons.

Am I doing something wrong, or is there a bug in registerTransactionEventHandler?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're lacking `tx.finish()` on the first transaction just after https://github.com/ttiurani/neo4j-uuid/blob/master/src/test/java/org/neo4j/extension/uuid/UUIDTransactionEventHandlerTest.java#L2. Therefore the transaction is not committed and the TransactionEventHandler not called, see http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/transactions-interaction.html.

Comment: thank you very very much :) . for neo4j version 2.0+ should call tx.close() because tx.finish() deprecated.

Comment: in Neo4j >= 2.0 you should create the transaction in a try-with-resources block. Since it is auto closable you don't need to explicitly call `close()`